# How to pass List<Objects> as parameter in IN Clause Spring Data Jpa method

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, spring-data-jpa

If it is like single value I know how to pass it like below method I'm looking for names

```
List<Object> findByNameIn(List<String> names);
```

But I have a requirement to check with both Name and Date column, so what I'm thinking is passing object. How can I do this like below in correct way?

The below code is just a dummy example of my idea.

```
Public Demo
{

private String name;
private Date date;

}

List<Object> findBy<>In(List<Demo> demos)
```

Comment: nobody is stopping you from writing your own sql. You should make sure to write compilable code, though, Public won't make the cut

Comment: Hi Stultuske, my doubt is how to give method name (findBy)in data jpa here if i pass  list demos parameter----- List<Object> findBy<>In(List<Demo> demos)

Comment: have you read the documentation of the framework you're trying to use?

Comment: Yes, but i didn't see any example of this type of scenario

Comment: It's unclear (to me at least) what exactly you want to achieve. If my guess is correct this is not possible. Did you try `findByNameInAndDateIn(names, dates)`?